# .NET 5 locking files vs. DFS Replication

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5, depth-first-search, dfs-replication

we have some web servers which are farmed, and we have DFS Replication set up on the `wwwroot` directory, so that we deploy to one server, and it updates the other servers.

Specifically only with .NET 5 sites (.NET Framework sites do not have this issue), we've seen that IIS (or maybe the IIS/Core shim or something else) seems to keep locks on the files (specifically EXEs and DLLs) and prevents DFS from being able to replicate the sites.

The users in charge of those sites have to recycle the app pools for their sites on the other servers, and then DFS is able to replicate.

Anyone have any ideas about this, or ways to make NET Core play nice with DFS, so that deploying sites doesn't require manual intervention on every server?

IIS is v.10.0.17763.1 on Windows Server 2019
DFS is configured on the web servers.
.NET Core is 5.0.9

Comment: Recycle the application pool before Publishing and that will release all locks on dll files. This seems to be the solution you are using now. `App_offline.htm` is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46496922/18789859), you can use it as a reference. Its downside is obvious, your website will be offline for a while. You can check [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3793) to view more about .Net Core file locking.

Comment: Yeah, we just found the `app_offline.htm` method last night. Not ideal, but it's something. Thanks for that github link, too. Looks like we're not even CLOSE to being the only one who is really unhappy about this "feature" in Core, when moving from Framework. 